# Flask denote begin / end of session

Tags: python, flask

Is there a possibility in flask to do something only once, e.g. when the app starts or gets shut down?

I need to store something in a file, when the flask app gets started, then be able to read it as long it is open and in the best case delete it, when the app is closed, or at least overwrite it in the next session.

I thought of declaring a "bool" "setup_done",
but I can't find a good place to declare it. I want it to stay, even though the page is refreshed, it should only be changed when the flask app itself is started or shut down.

My attempt was:

```
@app.route('/')
def myfunction:
    if not setup_done:
         do_setup()
         setup_done = True
    else:
         do_something_else()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_done=False
    app.run(debug=DEVELOPMENT_ENV)
```

But of course, here the variable setup_done is not known when used in myfunction.

I hope for a solution, which is based "simple programming", not importing new packages or functions.

I'm sorry if expressed poorly, I hope its clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple enough to do if you use the [application factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/) pattern.

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask('__name__')
    print("RUNNING SETUP TASKS") # This is where your function call goes
    return app

app = create_app()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You'll note that I didn't attach this to a base route (`@app.route('/')`) because that a) requires that the user visits that route and b) will be run every time someone visits that route. There are other mechanisms for that kind of thing like [`before_first_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request).

With that said, I will need to look into what happens if you start running the app through gunicorn (especially for things like `prefork`) because it's possible that your file-writing function will run multiple times; one for each process.

You jump interchangeability between "session" and "app". To give you more detail, I'd need to know exactly what it is that you're trying to do because these are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the bool variable outside of both function and after your imports. Something like this:

```
setup_done=False

@app.route('/')
def myfunction:
    if not setup_done:
         do_setup()
         setup_done = True
    else:
         do_something_else()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=DEVELOPMENT_ENV)
```

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. Pycharm still underlined it red in myfunction, and i get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'setup_done' referenced before assignment` when starting the app